# Table size in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, tablecell

I want something like this:

[image]

but I have some problems after the first row: the columns of the second row doesn't are how I want, but follows the first row format. I show you:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell Width="40%" runat="server">
            PARCELLA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="15%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
            N. FATTURA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="20%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
            DATA FATTURA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
            FIDUCIARIO
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    ....
</asp:Table>
```

I had tried another approach, where every row is declared like another different table, and works fine, but I didn't like this approach. Exists a way for use a unique table with row with different sizes?

Comment: Before I try to provide an answer, is there a specific reason you are using table to layout this?

EDIT: Ah, is it that you are going to do a printable PDF or something?

Comment: No, I thought it was the best thing to do... I have to insert in a aspx: a logo, this data (ordered like in the image), other text and, finally, another different table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ColumnSpan` property in the second row. Like this:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell Width="40%" runat="server" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1">
                PARCELLA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="15%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
                N. FATTURA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="20%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
                DATA FATTURA
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1" runat="server">
                FIDUCIARIO
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1">

        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1">

        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" HorizontalAlign='Center' BorderWidth="1">

        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

More information at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell.colspan(v=vs.110).aspx